Why does VGA sync have 50 Ω drivers but 75 Ω cables?
From what I managed to find about the VGA interface for computer displays, the RGB signals have a 75 Ω driver, a 75 Ω cable, and a 75 Ω load.  As expected.
The hsync and vsync signals are more complicated.  The source is 50 Ω.  The load is high impedance.  Long cables use 75 Ω for all the RGBHV signals while cheap cables only have controlled impedance for RGB.  An obvious downside of this configuration is more overshoot at the receiver.  A graphic card puts out edges faster than 80% of the fastest supported pixel clock period.  The 1024 x 768 at 85 Hz (non-interlaced) format has a pixel clock of 10.6 ns.  A graphic card that supports this format puts out edges faster than about 8 ns or 1.6 m in plastic.  With a 50 Ω source and a 75 Ω cable longer than that, the high impedance receiver sees an extra 20% overshoot in addition to the 30% that the source is allowed to put out.  It seems unhealthy for the receiver.
Why are the source impedance and cable impedance different?
Where I found the information.  Figure 1 on page 10 in the VESA Video Signal Standard says that the sources for the sync signals are 50 Ω.  Some websites for cable manufacturers such as this say that all the RGBHV cables are 75 Ω.
This question is not a duplicate of Why do VGA VSYNC and HSYNC need 47 ohm resistors in this schematic?.  It assumes that the source should be 75 Ω.

But most cables do not have 75 ohm coax for sync signals.

To be honest, VGA sync wires are not generally 75 ohms like you expect.
Originally, the VGA did not have 75 ohm coax for sync anyway, so it did not matter. The document you are reading for video signal specification is much later invention to try to standardize the VGA interface.
On for example IBM PS/2 Model 30-286, the HS and VS sync outputs are driven by 74LS125 LS TTL logic chip. There is a 10k pull-up to bring the TTL output to 5V because it would be less than 4V otherwise. There is also a 33 ohm series resistor and a 100pF filter capacitor to ground. All in all, what it really required is that voltage at source is more than 2.4V, or at least more than 2V at the monitor input.
Later VESA definition of using TTL voltage levels but with symmetric +/- 8mA drive means basically CMOS output and allows for 30% over/undershoot, and even ringing, as long the reflections do noy go into the 0.5V to 2.4V transition area.
Anyway, since it's now 8mA CMOS, driving 5V into 75 ohms cable or load would mean driving 67mA into the 75 ohms. Driving 5V into 50 ohms cable or load would be even worse, 100mA. The 8mA CMOS chip will not drive a 50 or 75 ohm cable well, it is too strong load. As source impedance from chip is 50 ohms, it means 40mA flowing into unterminated cable until signal reflections die out. And the VESA document still does not define impedance for the sync wires.
Defining a 50 ohm output impedance is rather easy, CMOS outputs are around 20-30 ohms anyway so add some 22 to 33 ohms as resistance. Driving a 75 ohm cable with 5V 50 ohm source resistance means that there will be a sync pulse of 3V being fed into the cable, assuming the driver can push enough current. And when the pulse pops up from the 75 ohm cable at monitor end into 2.2 kohm load, it will have a 5.8 V pulse amplitude. There will be reflection back to video card but amplitude is rather irrelevant, and some of the energy is terminated by the series resistor and CMOS impedance. Again there will be reflection back to monitor, but it will be a negative undershoot of about -1V.
In practice, the drivers can't drive tens of milliamps to cable and amplitudes and reflections are smaller. The monitor side can also be designed to clamp and handle the overshoots, undershoots and ringing.
And this is why normally the sync wires were not coaxial unless you bought a quintuple-BNC adapter or extension cable. The VGA output cannot drive very long 75 ohm coaxial sync wires due to impedance and capacitance. Logic chips are not very good cable drivers.
The sync impedance of more common VGA cable would have been higher which is why it works.
Also the IBM PS/2 analog output was not 75 ohms either. It was a current output DAC with 150 ohm termination to ground at source. The video cable and monitor termination were still 75 ohms.

Do I get this right?  VESA assumed that devices made after the spec came out would be CMOS instead of TTL.  They suggested an unloaded output impedance less than the impedance of commonplace cables.  This way enough signal can still go in to the cable for the receiver to switch on the first incident wave even when the driver's impedance increases due to large output current.

Is that 67 mA supposed to be 33 mA?  Since the other end is not terminated.

@o3pw5a3k0rzh Actually I made a mistake in calculations and will fix that. But if you connect a 75 ohm coax to a 5V voltage source, 67mA will flow into the cable until the 5V signal has traveled to open end of the cable and the reflected wave traveled back to source end. Here there is just 50 ohms in series with 5V source and cable, so 5V into 125 ohms is 40mA. Only when reflected wave bouncing is decayed there will be 5V on both ends of cable and 0mA flowing.

"5.8 ohm amplitude" should probably be 5.8 V.

There is a footnote in the VESA document that says you “should” make the horizontal sync cable impedance equal to the driver impedance. It sounds like a “stretch goal” recommendation and not a strict requirement. So if we followed that we should be making our HSYNC cable impedances 50ohm, but nobody does that as far as I know. It’s usually the uncontrolled  higher impedance (like you mention) when in a shielded wire bundle for DE15, or 75ohm when used with RGBHV 5x BNC. It sounds like in either case, the over/undershoot is not that big of a deal in the end. Am I understanding that correctly?

@SteKulov Right, not a big deal and in practice everyone making video cards or monitors will have to deal with any random cabling within some limits. DVI-A uses coaxial 75 ohms for HS but uncontrolled for VS

@Justme Ah, interesting. Thanks!

There are no performance issues as stated incorrectly. Therefore there is no real problem or cost reduction or performance improvement to create a change.  Proposal: Rejected.
There is no overshoot in the step pulse with a higher impedance load on a 30m cable since there is no reflection from a matched load and cable delay for baseband video is far less than risetime.  A 50-ohm SYNC line driver terminated with 50 Ohms will always drop 50% in voltage or any Zo impedance short cable (<10% wavelength) because there are no reflections.
Many older monitors and graphics cards were designed for 50 Ω sync signal in the TTL and RGB era and the defacto std for digital line drivers was 50 Ohms.  Even now 74HCxxx 5.5 V logic family has this legacy impedance. Ro=Vol/Io +/-xx %
Moving to a 75 Ω driver would not make any performance improvements.
There is no cost benefit to make any changes.

Racing to sync my answer.

But VGA sync wires do not terminate to 50 ohms. They terminate to 2200 ohms. Cable could be 75 ohm coax or just random wire. Source impedance is about 50 ohms.

Yes, I agree with the above. I believe you may have misunderstood the question.

Ok @Justme hen makes sense it is just TTL 2V  logic. I think you both misunderstand my answer . There is no reason to fix it. No problem. No overshoot . No wrong conclusion only load assumption. -1

@D.A.S. What happens if you simulate the same circuit except change the load to 2.2kohm?

It still meets TTL logic criteria between 0.8 and 2V.  I simulated with 50 ohm driver . But using TTL there will be more subtle differences  https://tinyurl.com/22sazcbr
